# Script triggered by crontab works differently than execute by user

Tags: c#, cron, mono, raspberry-pi3

I have the C# ConsoleApp.exe on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with Raspian. This program does simple process, it downloads and compare some data and than it post to discussion forum webpage. When I start this program on Windows 10, all is fine and works perfectly without problems.

On Raspian I start program with Mono cross-platform emulator and when I run .exe with right click in context menu and start with Mono (Terminal), with command "mono /home/pi/Desktop/app.exe" in terminal or when I execute script.sh with commands to start the app by mono inside, it also works same as on the Windows 10.

Problem: I need start this program in the morning/afternoon/evening everyday. In Windows 10 I used Task Scheduler and in the Raspian i used Cron.

Cron command: `18 7 * * * /home/pi/script.sh`

script.sh: `#!/bin/bash
mono /home/pi/Desktop/app.exe`

I don't run cron command: `18 7 * * * mono /home/pi/Desktop/app.exe`, because program doesn't start.

It's funny, because, program really start at 7:18 everyday and also write text file at the Desktop, but it doesn't make a POST to webpage. I'm using C# Http.Client in the program.

Do you know where is the problem ? Because I think the problem is that cron runs program on background and it isn't same as I execute script by myself or run it in Terminal.

Thanks for answers !

Http.Client Code:

```
  public static async Task writeNewAsync()
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = false });

                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://imhd.sk/po/pridaj-prispevok.php");

                request.Content = new StringContent("id=44&typ=0&parent=-1&login=User&heslo=password&text=TEST1", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", "cookie_notice=1");
                client.SendAsync(request);
            }
```

Comment: Are you logging all the errors?  Is the internet connection active when the program posts the data?

Comment: I don't logging errors. And internet connection works and is active.

Comment: Check the cron logs and see if you can get a clue from there.

Comment: There is only triggered of my script: `...(pi) CMD (home/pi/Destkop/myscript.sh)`

Comment: Try to turn on mono logs, and log all your calls, when connecting, closing the connection. Sometimes it complains with calls to https websites if your config specifies that don't trust all ssl certificates.

Comment: It looks like mono doesn't support Http.Client, when the program runs on the background. Because, as i wrote, when I execute by myself it works correctly and without problems.

Comment: Have you try changing Http.Client for HttpWebRequest? They made updates to this API in 2017, and seems to be working ok in linux

Comment: I add up here my code, but i don't how re-write to httpRequest...